# Cannot log into Sharepoint using my gmail account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, mac-os-x

My employee shared a folder with on Sharepoint, which I accessed using my Outlook account. My Outlook username is my gmail address (****@gmail.com). This works fine in the online environment, but I cannot:

1) Edit or open the file on my computer. When I try to edit it using Word or Excel on my computer, I get a log in prompt that keeps on looping. It never tells me that my password or login is incorrect, it merely keeps showing me the log in screen over and over again.

2) Synch the folder using OneDrive. When I click "synch" in the Sharepoint folder, it prompts a message from my browser (I have tried with both Safari and Chrome) asking me if its fine to open OneDrive. OneDrive does not open.

3) When I try to save a local file to the Sharepoint folder, I get the following message when I try to log in:

```
 gmail.com isn't in our system
 Make sure you typed your email address correctly. It usually looks like someone@example.com or someone@example.onmicrosoft.com
```

Which I do not understand because my microsoft account uses ***gmail.com as a log in. It works fine online, why would it not work locally?

Comment: Look at this article https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_account-mso_win10/office-365-account-crippled-by-email-address/48809df0-a843-4d91-8fee-349da1b98f6a